# How to create 2-D or 3-D curves to simulate something like the SIR model

Tags: broken-code

I don’t know what is wrong with my code. I am trying to create 2-D or 3-D curves to simulate something like the SIR model, but with tumor growth instead.

[image]

[image]

It is a proliferation-invasion/ reaction-diffusion model.

```
Clear[a, r, d, g];
a=1.03*10^(-3);
r=.20;
d=1*10^(-7);
g=1/4;
Clear[DE1,DE2, DE3, c,m,v,t,CMVsys]; Grad
DE1=D[c[x,y,z,t], t]\[Equal]Div[(a*(1-v[x,y,z,t]))*Grad[(c[x,y,z,t]),        {x,y,z}],{x,y,z}]+r*c[x,y,z,t]*(1-c[x,y,z,t]);
DE2=D[m[x,y,z,t],t]==Laplacian[(m[x,y,z,t]),{x,y,z}]+d*(c[x,y,z,t]- m[x,y,z,t]);
DE3=D[v[x,y,z,t],t]==v[x,y,z,t]*(1-v[x,y,z,t])-g*m[x,y,z,t]*v[x,y,z,t];
CMVsys={DE1,DE2,DE3};
Clear [solution, initial,cplot,mplot, vplot]; initial={c[x,y,z,0]==1,  m[x,y,z,0]==1, v[x,y,z,0]==1};
solution=Flatten[NDSolve[Join[CMVsys, initial], {c,m,v}, {t,0,800}]]
cplot=Plot[c[x,y,z,t]/.solution[[1]], {t,0,800}, PlotStyle-   >RGBColor[0,0,1], PlotRange-> {0,1}]
mplot=Plot[m[t]/.solution[[2]],{t,0,800}, PlotStyle->RGBColor[1,0,0]]
vplot=Plot[v[t]/.solution[[3]],{t,0,800},PlotStyle->RGBColor[0,1,0]]
Show[cplot, mplot, vplot, AxesLabel->{"t", "c=blue, m=red, v=green"}]
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/245107/edit) your question to add your code from the images. Posting the code makes it easier for us to try it by copying and pasting it rather than typing it from scratch.

Comment: I edited the code!

Comment: 1. There is a spurious `Grad` just before the definition of `DE1`; 2. don't you need to provide `NDSolve` with additional information regarding `x, y, z` ?

Comment: You need to give boundary conditions.